# How to set different env file with different bundle identifier?

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I use `react-native-config` with XCode setting.

I want to have three version are

myapp

```
Prod
```

myapp.Dev

```
Dev
```

myapp.Qa

```
Qa
```

Here is my step:

1. Adding new configurations Dev and Qa with XCode
2. Adding new schemes for Dev and Qa with XCode
3. set User-Defined for Dev and Qa with different bundle identifier

I run the project with XCode, It works, I can see three apps on simulator (Dev Qa Prod)

then I want to get variant from different file, so I set three env file

.env

```
API_URL=https://myapi.com
```

.env.dev

```
API_URL=https://myapi.dev.com
```

.env.qa

```
API_URL=https://myapi.qa.com
```

I also set the Run Script with XCode, for instance myapp.Dev is `cp "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env.dev" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env"`

I have two problems:

1. If run the project `myapp.Dev` with XCode

`get variable from .env (wrong) bundle identifier is Dev (correct)`

2. If I run the command `ENVFILE=.env.dev npx react-native run-ios` to build the project,

`get variable from .env file (wrong) and variable becomes to https://myapi.dev.com, bundle identifier is Prod (wrong)`

I have no idea what step is wrong, how do I just run `mypp.Dev` and read from `.env.Dev` file ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316899/build-run-two-targets-in-xcode-at-the-same-time).

It seems Xcode can only cope with one target at a time. It kinda caches the last target running. So if you build more than one at a time, you may find it keeps on reading the last .env.target file used.
Therefore:
Build only one instance from Xcode.
Build other/all instances of your app (schemes) from the console like so:

`npm run ios -- --scheme YourAppScheme`

Answer (score -2):

As my concern, I'm using this library :

[react-native-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config)

Comment: My problem just comes from `react-native-config`, thanks for your respond.